# Bazel Workspace depend on *.deb

Tags: bazel

What would be, in your opinion, the best way that a project can depend on another pre-compiled project that is distributed over debian packages?

A custom (new_)debian_package() workspace rule?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, I'd introduce a new `debian_package` rule that mimics what [`maven_jar`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#maven_jar) does.